# Java double avoid scientific notation but keep the data type

Tags: java, java-8, double, scientific-notation

How can I change scientific notation of a double in Java but keep the data type? I know about `DecimalFormat` and I don't want to print the value to output. I want to pass it along the pipeline as a double and not in scientific notation. For example I want `2000000000000` as a double and not in the form of `2.0E12`. Every solution I have found so far converts it to either a long or a big decimal or a string. Is it possible to keep it as a double?

Comment: What do you mean by "*pass it along the pipeline*"? As long as the value "stays" in Java, the bitpattern will stil be the same(`1000.0` is the same as `10e2` is the same as `1e3` is same as `1000e0`). The scientific notation is only a (de)serialization format.

Comment: @Turing85 At the end of the pipeline it is sent to an HTML page and it shows up as the scientific notation. I don't have access to that part of the pipeline so I can't change it there. I want to change it when it is generated instead.

Comment: Then you cannot keep it as `double`. The side that deserializes the value determines the format.

Comment: @Turing85 Oh... so double always changes it? That is problematic. Thanks for your help! I need to think.

Comment: No. The bitpattern of the `double` stays the same. The process deserializing the `double` (i.e. converting the `double` to a `String`) changes it.

Comment: Could you convert it to a String with your preferred formatting before passing it to the HTML page pipeline?

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan Theoretically yes, but I don't have access to that part of the code. So in reality, no.

Comment: So you are trying to solve a problem, you’re not responsible for. The one who converts the `double` to an HTML string, is responsible for the output format.

Comment: @Holger I was trying to prevent a problem. But it seems I can't.

Answer (score 0):

`double` does not encode any formatting information, only the value. The formatting is controlled by default by Double.toString, or the code that plugs values into the HTML page may be using a formatter.

One option is to replace your `double` with an instance of a wrapper class that carries a `double` field but has a toString method that does what you want. To do arithmetic, access the `double` field. The HTML page pipeline, finding a reference variable that is not one of the standard classes, is likely to call its toString to format the value.

Comment: If you can pass an arbitrary object to the HMTL pipeline, like the suggested wrapper, you can also pass a formatted string to it.